# Mobiscroll Default Date Value on Safari

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

I'm using mobiscroll date scroller in an app. I have it set up to initialize to a date I get from the database and set as the value of my input field. Here is my code:

```
                $(function(){

                    $("#requestDate").scroller({ 
                        preset: 'date',
                        theme: 'jqm',
                        display: 'modal',
                        mode: 'scroller',
                        dateOrder: 'mdyyyy',
                        dateFormat: 'm/d/yyyy'
                    });

                    var requestDate = $("#requestDate").val();

                    if(requestDate != ""){
                        requestDate = new Date(requestDate);
                        $("#requestDate").scroller('setDate', requestDate, true);
                    } 

                });
```

Here is my form field:

```
<input type="text" name="requestDate" id="requestDate" data-role="mobiscroll" value="2013,7,25" data-mini="true" readonly="" class="ui-input-text ui-body-f ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-mini">
```

This shows the date formatted in the text input and defaults to that date when mobiscroll is opened. Except for in Safari. In safari the date shows as NaN/NaN/NaN. How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `setDate`, just put the date in the correct format as the input value.
See example: http://jsfiddle.net/RQzbw/

Note 1: Use `'mdyy'` and `'m/d/yy'`, `yyyy` is incorrect (see documentation)

Note 2: `.scroller()` is deprecated, use `.mobiscroll()` instead. If you are using an older version, you should upgrade to latest.